# How can I expand the IE7 error message “This program cannot display the webpage” to Debug?

Tags: internet-explorer, http, fiddler

Is there a way to get Ie7 to expand on the error message “This program cannot display the webpage”?

I have turned off friendly error messages but this has not helped.

The background is that intermittently I get the error while using IE7 navigating to a around a particular a website. However I know the server has returned the web page with a 200 OK HTTP code as I can see this in fiddler. If I take the HTML code form the returned page out of fiddler and save it I can load it in IE with no issues.

Comment: Are there any further files embedded the page -- scripts, styles, images, object-embeds -- which might be failing to load?

Comment: No, it was all very odd in the end using https which oddly resolved the issues. At a guess I think it was a firewall problem but will never really know.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to debug in IE7 (I'm not a MS person).  In case it helps, it sounds like you may be hitting [a timing problem](http://www.bsalsa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=373) or interference with some antivirus software.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [HttpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com). The free basic edition shows error codes that were raised within IE and it may help you to diagnose this problem.

DISCLAIMER: this answer was provided by Simtec Limited the makers of HttpWatch